# Extremal of a functional $I=\int\limits_0^{x_1} y^2(y')^2dx$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations, calculus-of-variations

> The extremal of the function $$I=\int\limits_0^{x_1} y^2(y')^2dx$$ that passes through $(0,0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$ is
>
> 1. a constant function
> 2. a linear function of x
> 3. part of a parabola
> 4. part of an ellipse.

*Attempt:*

Using Euler-Lagrange equation,
$$\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial y}-\dfrac{d }{dx}\left(\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial y'}\right)=0$$
I get $$y^2y''+y(y')^2=0$$
Solving letting $v=y'$, $$\frac{y^2}2=cx+d,c=\frac{2x_1}{y_1^2}, d=0$$

Hence extremal is parabolic (right open).

Am I correct?

(CSIR June 2015, in case someone comes searching for it!)

Comment: I think you have an error in your application of EL.

Comment: @amcalde, fixed now?

Comment: OK better. I think I have an answer:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put
$$\frac{\partial (y^2(y')^2)}{\partial y}-\frac{d }{dx}\left(\frac{\partial  (y^2(y')^2)}{\partial y'}\right) = 0$$
$$2 y (y')^2 -\frac{d }{dx}\left(2 y^2 y'\right) = 0$$
Cancel the 2s then derivate:
$$y (y')^2 -2y(y')^2-y^2y'' = 0$$
$$y \left( (y')^2 + y y'' \right) = 0$$
Assuming that the function is not everywhere zero you get:
$$(y')^2 + y y'' = 0$$
Rearranging you get
$$\frac{d }{dx}(y y') = 0$$
Which we can take one step further to:
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(y^2) = 0$$
Which indeed means that if $y_1$ is zero then $y = y_0 = y_1$ a constant (everywhere zero afterall!). Or if not then, $y = \pm\sqrt{A x + B}$ as you say.

Since $y(0) = 0$, we have $B = 0$. Then $$y(x_1) = y_1 = \pm\sqrt{A x_1}$$
So $A = \frac{y_1^2}{x_1}$
Then both cases are covered by $y = \pm y_1 \sqrt{x/x_1}$

Comment: So its a constant function or part of a parabola? I was confused about $y(x)=0$, I think I shouldn't have ignored it!

Comment: See my update. Both cases are covered by this because $y = 0$ is a degenerate parabola after all.